# Small proximity of important points of a function

Tags: calculus, number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ be coprime integers with c greater than b and a,  $a^2 + b^2 \gt c^2$ and consider the function $f(x) = a^x + b^x - c^x$. It is easy to verify that there exist $r$ and $s$ such that $f(r) \ge f(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(s) = 0$. Prove the inequality below (in other words, when $c$ is big $r$ and $s$ are very close to each other  or even f-graph appears vertically from its peak).

$$ 0 < s-r < \frac{\ln(\ln c)}{\ln c}$$

Comment: You should assume that $c>\max\{a,b\}$, or otherwise $f(x)$ tends to infinity. Also, is it important that $a,b,c$ are integers?

Comment: Right Greg, I forget to add a<b<c (the condition about f(2) positive was just to be sure that s>2 which is not necessary).If you can add that condition, thanks very much. When I want to add it I cannot because the other part was disappeared. This is a question of my own since 3 or 4 years ago.

Comment: Note however that the zero s cannot exists if c don't satisfy a<b<c

Comment: Well, $s$ is the root of $a^x+b^x=c^x$, while $r$ is the root of $a^x\ln a+b^x\ln b=c^x\ln c$. And $b>\frac c2$ by your inequalities, so $\ln b$ isn't too far from $\ln c$ - maybe you can get some mileage out of that....

Comment: @Greg Martin, that "mileage" is just the question.

Comment: Yep. But since you didn't indicate any thoughts or partial progress whatsoever in your question, I decided to take a little time and write something that might help. If you have already done some work and don't want people to repeat it, you should say so in detail in the original post.

Comment: @Greg Martin, If you want you might try to see very clearly my short answer.Regards.

Answer (score -1):

An answer is,concisely,as follow:

[image]

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths on this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation). Particularly, since searching in images is hard, posting image answers is not appropriate.

Comment: @Lord_Farin. Thanks for your comment. I do not know how to write in the language of this site and on the other hand I can clearly read the figure. Perhaps it would be better to stop sending posts